# Call function in class stored in map

Tags: c++, class, hashmap

I recently started using C++ a lot more and to get better at it I'm creating a basic voxel game that's a clone of what I did when learning Java. (think basic minecraft)

The main game loop calls a `draw()` method in the `World` class, which then loops through all the chunks and calls a draw method on the chunks. In order to both save memory usage, and to have non-square shaped worlds, the chunks are stored in a map where the key is a class that stores the chunk position in `chunk space`. (chunk space is essentially `chunkx = floor(worldx/chunksize)`)

I believe the way I am currently calling the `.draw()` function on the `chunks` in the `map` is not correct because the code to build the chunk mesh which is only suppose to be called once is being called over and over.

The world's draw function:

```
void World::draw () {
    std::map<ChunkPosition, Chunk>::iterator it = chunks.begin();
    while (it != chunks.end()) {
        ChunkPosition pos = it->first;
        Chunk chunk = it->second; // I think I may need to use a pointer here somehow

        chunk->draw();
        it++;
    }
}
```

The Chunk's draw function:

```
void Chunk::draw () {
    if(build){ // should only "build" the mesh once, is initialized to true
        build = false;

        ... mesh building code that is not relevant ...

        std::cout << verticeSize << std::endl; // this is called every loop cycle instead of once

        mesh.build (vertices, verticeSize, indices, indiceSize);
    }

    mesh.draw(); // draw the mesh every cycle
}
```

And here is the Chunk class's structure

```
class Chunk {
    private:
        static const int size = 25;
        std::map<Location, Block> blocks;
        Mesh mesh;
        bool build = true;
    public:
        void setBlock (Location, Block&);
        void setBlock (int, int, int, Block&);
        Block *getBlock (Location);
        Block *getBlock (int, int, int);
        bool hasBlock (Location);
        bool hasBlock (int, int, int);
        void draw ();
};
```

I have a single chunk in the `chunks` map at position `(0,0,0)`. Everything else about it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: `Chunk chunk = it->second;` should be `Chunk& chunk = it->second;` to avoid copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you're making a copy of the chunk stored in the map here:

```
Chunk chunk = it->second;
```

You should instead access a reference. This can be done like this:

```
Chunk& chunk = it->second;
```

but it may be easier to use a range-based for loop instead of the complicated while loop:

```
for (auto& chunk : chunks) chunk.second.draw();
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I assumed that was what was happening but totally forgot about references :)